# mongod config file production

Tags: mongodb, configuration-files

I find this forum so helpful!

Quick question here… I have installed mongodb many times on personal laptops to play around; didn’t care much about the options…now I have to install for a project, it will be **production**…

How should my config file look like, if I want to put the data files in drive e: and enable journaling, and put journaling files on f: drive… I checked some of the documents; but there might be many options that I pick default, and I may regret in the future.

I always installed the 2.0 version, now I want to install the latest ‘Current Stable Release (3.0.3)’, I really don’t want to mess with the parameters… Any help with the config file, and best practices/lesson learned, would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer to these questions depends upon what data you will be storing, what will be the access patterns/queries?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am still trying to figure that out...

What about journal files and data files... they should be separeted in diferent disks right? actually different disk array right? Is there any official documentation supporting this?

Comment: Yes, documentations are available but you need be sure about your setup/queries/users/data everything. Then only you will be able to find best solution for you. Otherwise you will find every new setup as best choice for you which might not be true.

Comment: Thanks!! I wasn't able to separate the datafiles from the journal (in different drives); if I change the path, the journal will also go to that same path...